# Symfony Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8

Tags: windows, symfony, character-encoding, xampp, symfony-2.8

I am facing this error while running the Symfony 2.8 project on my windows machine. I have read all the related questions available in this forum and tried every one of them but no luck. Did anyone face this issue?

Note: This project works fine in ubuntu system without any issue.

Can anyone of you give me an input which will help me to resolve this issue?

The full error in the command line is,

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24445) is related and according to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24445#issuecomment-334920642) comment you need to either update your project to 3.x (or 4.x) or eliminate the reason of the issue from your code.

Comment: Thanks for this. But this issue is in another file but the same trick worked.